# How can i set javaFX Menubutton text to the selected menuItem text

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, javafx-8

Here is what I have tried.

FMXL

```
<MenuButton fx:id="start_hour" layoutX="146.0" layoutY="267.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#set_start_min" text="Start Hour" />
```

Initializing my menu items in my controller. I am doing this because I have several buttons that can easily be set using loops.

```
  public void initialize() {

        ObservableList<MenuItem> start_hourItems = start_hour.getItems();

        for (int i = 1; i < 13 ; i++) {
            MenuItem mi = new MenuItem(Integer.toString(i));
            start_hourItems.add(mi);

        }

    }
```

HANDLING THE EVENT (I realize this is wrong and not working, but wanted to include it as to show my attempt. )

```
public void set_start_min(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

// create action event
EventHandler<ActionEvent> event1 = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        start_min.setText(((MenuItem)e.getSource()).getText());
    }
};

// add action events to the menuitems
start_min.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) actionEvent);


}
```

Last here is an image of it **not** working correctly. If it were working correctly the main menu button text would change with the selection.
[image]

Comment: You should probably be using a [`ChoiceBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) or [`ComboBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html) instead of a `MenuButton`.

Comment: @Slaw. Thanks! Keeping the question up just in case this is useful for someone else.